# prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin(kA)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin(kA)} = {{\cos({A\over2})-\cos(nA+{A\over 2})}\over 2\sin({A\over 2})}$$using Telescoping series. How do i go about doing this?

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times, I'm sure a search will turn up something.

Comment: I could not find anything can you post a link to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the trigonometric identity:
$$2\sin x \sin y = \cos(x - y) - \cos(x + y).$$
Multiply both sides by $2\sin(A/2)$, it follows that 
\begin{align*}
& 2\sin(A/2)\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \sin(kA) \\
= & 2\sin(A/2)\sin(A) + 2\sin(A/2)\sin(2A) + \cdots + 2\sin(A/2)\sin(nA) \\
= & \cos(A/2 - A) - \cos(A/2 + A) + \cos(A/2 - 2A) + \cos(A/2 + 2A) + \cdots \\  & + \cos(A/2 - nA) + \cos(A/2 + nA) \\
= & \cos(A/2 - A) + \cos(A/2 + nA) \\
= & \cos(A/2) + \cos(A/2 + nA)
\end{align*}
where we used $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$ to make the telescoping possible.